# android countdown timer continues to run in background

Tags: java, android

I want to make a 30 second countdown to run in my activity and continue to run until it hits 0. Is there any method?

Basically I want it to run and update its value in a textview.

Comment: Your title and description mismatch.

Comment: bad misleading title and an question 99% lies somewhere on the board already.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way

```
 new CountdownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
  }.start()
```

;

Answer (score 0):

Check this: http://coderzheaven.com/2011/08/simple-countdown-timer-in-android/ for a complete example using CountDownTimer.